# display: table и все с ним связанное

Tags: css

Всем привет. Есть несколько вопросов по использованию display: table;

- Рационально ли делать верстку на основе display: table?
- Как объединять ячейки внутри элемента с display: table-row?
- Почему header c классом .row в коде ниже не заполняет всю ширину таблицы?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}
header.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: silver;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #fff;
}
aside,
section {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 20px;
}
section {
  padding-right: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  border-right: 1px solid silver;
}
aside {
  width: 300px;
}
footer {
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  border-top: 1px solid silver;
  background: #f5f5ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper table">
  <header class="row">
    <div>Почему header.row не  заполняет всю ширину таблицы</div>
  </header>
  <div class="row">
    <section class="cell"></section>
    <aside class="cell"></aside>
  </div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: На мой взгляд табличная верстка нужна только для таблиц и ничего более, даже в для форм авторизации / регистрации лучше этого не делать. Половина данного сообщества решает свои проблемы именно данным способом, потому что многие выросли на `table`. Это что то вроде того, что если бы вы писали на `php` 5 лет, а потом вам сказали, что это никому не нужно, кроме "бедных" фирм, заказчик которых не готов выплатить больше денег за решение "шаблонной" задачи, думаю вы бы настояли на том, что php это хорошо, т.к. вы не готовы перешагнуть через себя и перейти на `ruby`, `python` или `node.js`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Рационально ли делать верстку на основе `display: table?`**

Со времен табличной верстки в `html` и `css` появилось множество улучшений, которые заменяют ее собой. Проблема табличной верстки в том, что с ней не добиться адаптивности (или весьма тяжело добиться). При изменении содержимого какой либо ячейки происходит пересчет всей таблицы (расходует ресурсы). Табличную верстку сложнее поддерживать.

Таким образом использовать верстку на основе таблиц не рационально.

Таблицы лучше использовать по их прямому назначению - для отображения таблиц.
Табличную верстку можно применять, например, при печати странички.

**2. Как объединять ячейки внутри элемента с `display: table-row?`**

В `css` нет аналога `colspan`, поэтому ваш `header` отображается в одной колонке а не занимает две.

**3. Почему `header` c классом `.row` в коде ниже не заполняет всю ширину таблицы?**

По той же причине, что и предыдущем пункте.

*Скорее всего ваша задача может быть решена без использования табличной верстки.*

Если вам требуется центрировать содержимое по горизонтали, то есть `margin`, `position: absolute`, `flexbox`, `text-align для inline-block` и другие возможности в зависимости от конкретной задачи и требований к совместимости с различными браузерами.

Для вертикального позиционирования вы так же можете использовать `flexbox`, `position: absolute`, оборачивание в контейнер с `display: table-cell;` совместно с `vertical-align`, `line-height` для однострочного текста и другие методы в зависимости от конкретной задачи.

Answer (score 3):

display:table; единственный конкурент flexbox , на [Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/281254/) есть статья по этому поводу

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Плюсую за полезную ссылку.

Comment: я рад что помог